# Pass parameter from html select tag to controller

Tags: visualforce, controller, html, parameters, selectoption

I want to pass parameter that selected from html select tag to my controller (assign it to string "city")
what should i do to achieve this ?

--Visualforce--

```
<select> 
      <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">City</option> 
      <option value="City A">City A</option> 
      <option value="City B">City B</option> 
      <option value="City C">City C</option> 
</select>
```

--Apex Class--

```
public String city{get;set;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `<apex:selectlist>` and `<apex:selectOption>`

Use selected/disabled attribute of `<apex:selectOption>`

```
<apex:selectlist value="{!city}" size="1"> 
      <apex:selectOption itemlabel="City" itemValue=""/>
      <apex:selectOption itemlabel="City A" itemValue="City A"/>
      <apex:selectOption itemlabel="City B" itemValue="City B"/>
      <apex:selectOption itemlabel="City C" itemValue="City C"/>
</apex:selectlist>
```

---

Or

Use `<apex:inputHidden>`

```
<apex:inputHidden value="{!city}" id="cityId"/> 

<select onchange="document.getElementById('{!$Component.cityId}').value = this.value;"> 
      <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">City</option> 
      <option value="City A">City A</option> 
      <option value="City B">City B</option> 
      <option value="City C">City C</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: Hi Ratan, thanks for your response. i already try that before and it success. but i want do it with html <select> tag not <apex:selectList>.

Comment: @FebrianTarigan so it is working or not ?

Comment: need to use html <select> not <apex:selectList>

Comment: @FebrianTarigan `<apex:selectList>` will generate `<select> `... ohk no problem check my updated Ans use `<apex:inputHidden>`

Comment: can i use this for multiselect true ? did it get the values or just one value ?

Comment: @FebrianTarigan yes you can use. What I remembered you give values with `;` separated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33850/discussion-between-febrian-tarigan-and-ratan).